# Could not initialize com.android.xml.androidxpathfactory

Tags: android, apk

I am facing weird problem. I want to upload my app on Google Play store. For that, I am trying to generate signed APK but using Eclipse export tool. But whenever I try generating it, that throws following error message

**could not initialize class com.android.xml.androidxpathfactory**

Above thing happens when I am at last step of generating **signed apk** and click **Finish** button. Please see below error pop up dialog.

[image]

I don't understand what's going wrong with it.

Comment: you might have problem with your proguard configuration, could you show us console log?

Comment: Actually, There are now log generating while I try to generate signed apk

Comment: try to generate your app from console

Comment: I need answer for my question. i don't want workaround for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately, I have found solution after trying a lot. The problem was this above class file was missing in my `googols-play-services`. jar file. I fixed it by updating my `google-play-services.jar` file.

Answer (score 0):

I use phonegap.

In Project menu, uncheck 'build automatically'. than restart eclipse.

This solved it for me.

NOTE: I also install the app on a real device, it might also helped...

NOTE: I'm not sure if restarting eclipse is necessary.

Answer (score -1):

In my case, the issue was fixed by switching my Eclipse (Luna 4.4.1 on Mac OS Maverick) from Java 7 to Java 6 as described in the below step:

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=68755